# router-link and href not working in Vue js

Tags: routes, vue.js, routerlink

I am learning vue js and i created an admin page which i am able to route when i am using router-view but when i am trying href or router-link i am not able to load the template thought the url gets changed.

**this is my main.js**

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
    import App from './App.vue'

    import admin from "./components/admin/admin.vue"
    import users from "./components/users.vue"


    Vue.use(VueRouter);
    Vue.use(VueResource);

    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes: [
            {path:'/admin',component:admin},
            {path:'/users',component:users},

        ]
    })


    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        router: router,

        render: h => h(App)
    })
```

**this is my app.vue**

this is my app vue file which just want to route to a page via href

```
    <template>
      <div class = "container" id="app">

          <h1>Hi from</h1>

          <hr>
          <a href="/api/users">sdsd</a>


      </div>
    </template>

    <script>


    export default {
      name: 'app',

      data(){
        return{
          users: ""
        }
      }
    }
    </script>

    <style>
    #app {

    }
    </style>
```

**this is my admin.vue**

this the template i want to load in my app.vue its a simple template i want to display in app.vue. its somehow working router-view but it is not working with router-link

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>
            HI i am routing from admin
        </h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

the above thing is working via router-view but not thing router-link or href anchor tags............................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 7):

1.You are building a SPA using vue and vue-router. The routing is handled by javascript only. So you do not need to pass URLs to href in `<a>` tags .

2.You should use `<router-link>` for navigation which will eventually be rendered as `<a>` tag.

3.You use `to` attribute of `<router-link>` as a prop to pass the link you want to navigate to.

4.You require `<router-view></router-view>` to display or render the component matched by the roite.

So your **App.vue** should be:

```
<template>
  <div class = "container" id="app">

      <h1>Hi from App.vue</h1>

      <hr>
      <router-link to="/users">Users</router-link>
      <router-link to="/admi">Admin</router-link>
    
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'app',

  data(){
    return{
      users: ""
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {

}
</style>
```

Comment: hello 
I have been trying to use router-link too when that didn't work i tried <a>  tag

Comment: @KushagraAgarwal i reproduced the same code here https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/zysj2meg/  it works fine

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```html
<router-link to="/" custom 
    v-slot="{ href, navigate, isActive }">
    <li :class="{ active: isActive }">
        <a :href="href" @click="navigate">
           Home
        </a>
    </li>
</router-link>
```